# Free throw Probability

Tags: probability

> Suppose a basketball player has an 80 percent chance of making a free throw. He has been fouled, and has two free throws. If a free throw is made, its counts as one point. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the number of points from the first and second free throw respectively. Figure out the joint probabilities for $X$ and $Y$, the expected number of points from the two free throws, and the variance for this number of points, when:
>
> a) each free throw is an independent event
>
> b) $P(Y=1\mid X=1)=0.9$ and $P(Y=1\mid X=0)=0.4$ so that making the first free throw raises the probability of making the second free throw.

So I've pretty much done part a but the only thing I'm confused about is when I find the expected number of points from the two free throws its less than 1. Should it be that way? Than, for part b it only gives me two of the probabilities and I'm a little confused about how to find the other two. I tried setting it up into a two by two box with X values on top and Y values on the side but still couldn't figure that out. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, many would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Figure out..."), not a request for help, so consider rewriting it.

Comment: Thanks! The "figure out" was just part of the problem itself so I wasn't trying to be rude or anything. I'll keep all that in mind and I appreciate it.

Comment: Another user asked this question one day later, but [the other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295268/free-throw-probability-and-expected-number-of-points) has a more detailed answer.  (FYI for future visitors)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Find out the results of the 4 cases first:

$$\text {with} \space P(Y=1\mid X=1)=0.9 \space \text{you can find}\space P(Y=0 \mid X=1) = 0.1$$
$$\text {with} \space P(Y=1\mid X=)=0.9 \space \text{you can find}\space P(Y=0 \mid X=1) = 0.1$$